# How to dispose resources in third-party dll?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application that needs to create multiple objects of type `<T>` and `T` is inside another dll that I don’t own.

When an object of type `T` is created, it loads a XML in memory, but it never releases it. 
So if you create too many objects of type `T`, an OutOfMemoryException is thrown.
The dll doesn't provide a dispose method for that Object and I can’t interact with the XML directly.

> Is there a way to dispose of objects of a certain type that were created by a dll that I don’t own ?

I'm using .NET 4.6

The third-party dll is the dll of **Trados Studio**, for the people who know the program.

Comment: can you load it in a different appdomain? sounds like you need to file a bug report with them.

Comment: In fact, the dll needs to be in the same folder that my application otherwise I get a LicensingException from the dll. Why loading it in a different appdomain could resolve the problem?

Comment: you can unload app domains. you can't unload a direct reference.

Comment: You can unload an app domain.

Comment: Do you need to dispose? It should be enough to simply let GC take care of it, or does the object store static references to said xml documents?

Comment: I will give it a try with appdomain. I need to dispose. It loads objects in loh and it doesn't stop to increase. I use a memory profiler to detect the problem.

Comment: Will simply setting the instance to null and creating a new one not allow the garbage collector to dispose of it?

Comment: @DanielA.White : It works perfectly loading it in a different appdomain! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just set the instance of the 3rd part object to null and create a new instance. The garbage collector will eventually clean up the object that you set to null and you wont get an out of memory exception anymore.

```
public class Class1
{
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public void loadFile()
    {
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt"))   // Loads large text file. 
        {
            sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    fileloader.Class1 inst = new fileloader.Class1(); // Assume this is the instance of your 3rd party object. 

    do
    {
        if(inst == null)
        {
            inst = new fileloader.Class1();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            inst.loadFile();
        }

        inst = null;  // allows the object to be GC'ed. Without this i get the OutOfMemoryException

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the memory is still increasing.

Comment: @Claudia The memory will increase but the Garbage Collector will not let it get to the point of failure. The GC will only run when it decides it needs to. In my example program that i posted the memory in use bounced between 300-600mb. Can you try and replicate the failure? How long does it take to fail?

Comment: It fails after executing 900 operations.

Comment: @Claudia They must be using a static variable to store the information. The static variable wont get GC'ed.

Comment: @Claudia Is there somewhere i can get this DLL and can you supply some basic code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to get the license of the application (Trados Studio Professionnal), otherwise the dll throw a LicensingException.

Answer (score 0):

Calling GC.Collect() during runtime might solve the problem.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-5.0